# Using std::thread in Node.js Addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, multithreading, node.js-addon

Imagine that I use a synchronous function, from my Node.js addon:

```
var check_ok = addon.my_function(parameters);
var final_results = addon.final_function(parameters);
```

But in the method code I have:

```
std::thread t[10]; //Global
//...
void my_function(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
//....
t[0] = thread(random_void_function, [parameters])
t[1] = thread(random_void_function_2, [parameters])
//...
}
//...
void final_results(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
//...
t[0].join();
t[1].join();
//...Give results.. etc
}
```

So I have 2 synchronous calls of addon, but in this addon two threads are used. One function will start the threads and the other will join them. The questions are: `random_void_function` and `random_void_function_2` will run in parallel? Since `my_function` and `final_function` are synchronous, the `random_void_function` and `random_void_function_2` will block the event loop? From what I see, they not block.

Comment: I know nothing of Node.JS, but from C++ point of view those two functions will run in parrallel and will not block anything (unless they call some blocking functions themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The questions are: random_void_function and random_void_function_2 will run in parallel?

Yes, provided they live long enough.  If they are short-lived, an equally plausible outcome is that the first starts and exits prior to the second starting and exiting (or visa versa).

> Since my_function and final_function are synchronous, the random_void_function and random_void_function_2 will block the event loop? From what I see, they not block.

No and maybe.  `addon.my_function` will *not* block the event loop.  `addon.final_results` (which I assume you meant to call above instead of `addon.final_function`) will only block if the `random_void_function`s are long- lived.  If they are short lived and have already exited, `addon.final_results` will exit immediately.

Since you are not seeing any blocking, I suspect the `random_void_function`s are short-lived.

Comment: My mistake.. `final_function` is an asynchronous function. That's why is not blocking. Considering the question as it is, I agree with you.